# Jacobson radical, how to visualize all simple R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am not very strong in ring theory and I am trying to understand the Jacobson radical.

The Jacobson radical $J(R)$ of a ring $R$ is defined to be the ideal of $R$ of all $r\in R$ such that $rM=0$ for all simple $R$-modules $M$.

What I don't understand, is, given a ring R, how can we characterize the set of all simple R-modules M over R? There should be infinitely many. How can we even consider them all? How can we construct them? Is it possible to do this in practice, or must we get to J(R) in another way?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: About the set of simple $R$-modules: What if $R$ is local, or even a field?

Answer (score 3):

*how can we characterize the set of all simple R-modules M over R? […] How can we even consider them all? How can we construct them?*

There is a [well-known correspondence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281064) of isoclasses of simple module with maximal one sided ideals.  This is why the Jacobson radical can be equivalently be formulated in terms  of maximal right ideals.

*There should be infinitely many.*

What? Why? There is sometimes only even one.